# JPQL : How to construct a WHERE clause?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

i would like to create a namedquery in JPQL, but i don't understand how it's working...

Here my entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "Translation.lang", 
                query = "SELECT t FROM Translation t WHERE t.reference.id = :refId AND t.language.lang = :lang")
})
@Table(name = "T_E_TRANSLATION_TRL")
public class Translation implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "TRL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
@TableGenerator(name="translationSeqStore", 
    table="T_S_APP_SEQ_STORE_AST", 
    pkColumnName="AST_SEQ_NAME",
    valueColumnName = "AST_SEQ_VALUE",
    pkColumnValue = "T_E_TRANSLATION_TRL.TRL_ID", 
    allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, 
    generator="translationSeqStore")            
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRL_REF_ID", nullable = false)  
private Reference reference;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRL_LAN_ID", nullable = false)  
private Language language;

@Column(name = "TRL_LABEL", nullable = false, length = 4000)    
private String label;
```

Should i use LEFT JOIN on Reference & Language to select my translatation with these id ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t FROM Translation t join fetch t.reference join fetch t.language WHERE t.reference.id = :refId AND t.language.lang = :lang
```

That will join (and fetch the LAZY reference and language) and return the `Translation`s for the reference with ID `refId` and language with lang = `lang`.

Comment: Ok, i don't really know what i was doing. So, when lazy and join are present, we have to use "join fetch" in order to realize a search on these criteria ? Thank you.

Comment: You don't _have to_ but it avoids an extra query to fetch it when you try and access it lazily...

Comment: oki...it's really the lazy mode the important element :) Thank you.

Comment: And how to manage that if the element is a Set ?

i.e how to make a research on Id of a specific element...

Here an example :

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinTable(name = "T_J_MAN_AIR_MNA", 
      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MNA_MAN_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MNA_AIR_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }) 
 private Set<Aircraft> aircrafts = new HashSet<Aircraft>(0);


SELECT m FROM Manual m join fetch ? WHERE ???

Comment: Fetching works the same way for Sets, `join fetch m.aircrafts`, for the `where` clause, you'll need to use something like `EXISTS` (refer to the JPQL Language Reference)

Comment: Is `join fetch` ok for many relations ? I would like to create a namedquery where i will do something like that..... `SELECT a FROM aircraft a JOIN FETCH a.references r JOIN FETCH a.references.referenceType rft WHERE rft.Id = :id` Is it possible to join a third entity in the relation ? Thank you.

Comment: No, because I do not SQL very often, but it's hard to me to pass on the HQL or JPQL. And I even have trouble finding documentation on this, on more complex cases than the simple relationships. I have a typical example using the IN, similar to an inner join. But not with more relationships, with more tables. And sometimes it's difficult to me to test my namedqueries. I dunno if there is a good way to test before execute my website.

Comment: Is there a simple way to test JPQL with Eclipse ?

Comment: Sure, you should implement a simple test class with JUnit or TestNG and test your code from there, much faster and easier to learn and experiment...

Comment: is that JPQL more cleaner in my case?
`SELECT DISCTINCT  a FROM Aircraft a JOIN FETCH a.references r WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ref FROM Reference ref WHERE ref = r AND ref.refTypeId: id)`

Comment: sure :-) you should probably create new questions if you need to ask about specific modelling questions though, this question is answered... - your last query looks _reasonable_ but I can't comment on whether it will work without seeing your classes

Comment: yeah i will create a new question coz my query is not working :(